# Ignore in swagger and make required in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, webapi

how to make a model have a mandatory field in the database but ignore it in swagger? I already used [JSONIGNORE] but it is still mandatory in swagger.

Comment: You might hide it in swagger but it will still be in your Rest API and available. To be correct you really should think about distinct models. One (at least one for the API) and one for persisting.

Comment: Is doing this correct or is it bad practice?

Comment: Having multiple distinct models fitting to the domain its used in is a good thing. Reusing a model and trying to make it fit everywhere is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you should 2 separate models, as this looks like 2 separate layers, one for presentation and another for persistence.

Then you would have one model for users, that use the app, and the other for data that you store.
However, this looks very strange, because users will get failed requests for a property that is not required (that's what they will see in swagger), but errors will show up in database.

Comment: Well, I can imagine situations where you can set some required properties in your code based on requirements, and you don't want to bother users with that. For example, mandatory modified date property.

Comment: A better example for you to understand, would be a field that the user would not inform, this field would be filled by my own system, during the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-newtonsoftjson-based-json-format-support-1):

As mentioned in it:

Some features may not work well with System.Text.Json-based formatters and require a reference to the Newtonsoft.Json-based formatters. Continue using the Newtonsoft.Json-based formatters when the app:

Uses Newtonsoft.Json attributes. For example, `[JsonProperty]` or `[JsonIgnore]`.

So Check the [JsonIgnore] attribute is [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]or      [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]

[image]

[image]